# Проблема работы selenide с таймером

Tags: java, таймер, selenide

моя программа обновляет постоянно страницу в инстаграмме, через таймер, вот код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration.browserPosition = "5000x5000";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\chromedriver.exe");// "C:\\Users\\"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");


        open("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=ru");


        $(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input")).setValue("LOGIN").pressEnter();
        $(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input")).setValue("PASSWORD").pressEnter();
    $(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")).click();
     final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
     ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() { Selenide.refresh();  }
     }, 2, 600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

но почему-то, на том моменте, когда начинает работать таймер, selenide перестает работать, и выбрасывает ошибку:

```
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:29 PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.LazyDriver getAndCheckWebDriver
INFO: No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1 - let's create a new webdriver
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 32334
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:33 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.BrowserResizer adjustBrowserSize
INFO: Set browser size to 1366x768
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:33 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.BrowserResizer adjustBrowserPosition
INFO: Set browser position to 5000x5000
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:33 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory logBrowserVersion
INFO: BrowserName=chrome Version=78.0.3904.87 Platform=XP
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:33 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory createWebDriver
INFO: Selenide v. 5.3.1
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:33 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory logSeleniumInfo
INFO: Selenium WebDriver v. 3.141.59 build time: 2018-11-14T08:25:48
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:33 PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CreateDriverCommand createDriver
INFO: Create webdriver in current thread 1: ChromeDriver -> ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (f00af332118c63fce54241dcbe772091)
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:43 PM com.codeborne.selenide.impl.UnusedWebdriversCleanupThread closeUnusedWebdrivers
INFO: Thread 1 is dead. Let's close webdriver com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver@48ab8b1a
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:43 PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CloseDriverCommand run
INFO: Close webdriver: 10 -> ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (f00af332118c63fce54241dcbe772091)
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:43 PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CloseBrowser run
INFO: Trying to close the browser ChromeDriver ...
ноя 02, 2019 1:09:44 PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CloseDriverCommand run
INFO: Closed webdriver 10 in 863 ms
```

я пробовал делать таймер по другому:

```
 new java.util.Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {Selenide.refresh();}
        },1000*2,1000*2);
```

но все так же, но вылетала другая ошибка

```
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:20 PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.LazyDriver getAndCheckWebDriver
INFO: No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1 - let's create a new webdriver
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 31135
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:24 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:24 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.BrowserResizer adjustBrowserSize
INFO: Set browser size to 1366x768
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:25 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.BrowserResizer adjustBrowserPosition
INFO: Set browser position to 5000x5000
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:25 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory logBrowserVersion
INFO: BrowserName=chrome Version=78.0.3904.87 Platform=XP
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:25 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory createWebDriver
INFO: Selenide v. 5.3.1
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:25 PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory logSeleniumInfo
INFO: Selenium WebDriver v. 3.141.59 build time: 2018-11-14T08:25:48
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:25 PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CreateDriverCommand createDriver
INFO: Create webdriver in current thread 1: ChromeDriver -> ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (78cde372477ed6c94ffd830bf02ffa8f)
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No webdriver is bound to current thread: 20. You need to call open(url) first.
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.LazyDriver.getWebDriver(LazyDriver.java:67)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.refresh(Navigator.java:171)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.refresh(SelenideDriver.java:114)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.refresh(Selenide.java:174)
    at TestAll.Selend$1.run(Selend.java:41)         
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:37 PM com.codeborne.selenide.impl.UnusedWebdriversCleanupThread closeUnusedWebdrivers
INFO: Thread 20 is dead. Let's close webdriver com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver@219a0906
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:40 PM com.codeborne.selenide.impl.UnusedWebdriversCleanupThread closeUnusedWebdrivers
INFO: Thread 1 is dead. Let's close webdriver com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver@6e60e97e
ноя 02, 2019 1:15:40 PM com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CloseDriverCommand run
INFO: Close webdriver: 10 -> ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (78cde372477ed6c94ffd830bf02ffa8f)
```

Comment: Selend.java:41-это Selenide,refresh();

Comment: и если убрать Configuration.browserPosition = "5000x5000"; все равно та же ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ох, жесть...

Селенид открывает отдельный браузер на каждый поток - для параллельного запуска тестов. ScheduledExecutorService запускает ваш Runnable в новом потоке. Поэтому команда Selenide.refresh(), запущенная в отдельном потоке, открывает новый браузер, а не рефрешит существующий.

Может, вы лучше скажите, чего хотите добиться? 
По-моему,  ScheduledExecutorService там не нужен.

Comment: я хочу чтобы каждые 2 секунды, обновлялась страничка.

Comment: может можно какими-то окольными путями обойти это?

Comment: впринципе я могу обернуть весь код в таймер, и дальше по ходу программы, убрать повторение захода и открытие браузера через if/else. Но может можно сделать как-то по другому?

Comment: @AvramCholoshen Зачем нужно, чтобы каждые 2 секунды обновлялась страничка?

Comment: это суть задания, которое мне дали

Comment: нужно просто обновление странички. Я думаю все в таймер сделать, но это какой-то неправильный вариант мне кажется

Comment: Суть любого задания - посмотреть, какие дополнительные вопросы человек будет задавать. Если попросить сделать дурость и он ломанётся делать дурость без лишних вопросов - считай, провалил. Надо понять, зачем нужно обновлять страницу. Для чего? Какую проблему решаем? Что делать дальше после обновления?

Answer (score 0):

после выполнения open(), сохраняй текущий webDriver, а после вызова refresh - восстанавливай webDriver

```
WebDriver webDriver;

// constructor
public SelenideCommand() {
    Configuration.holdBrowserOpen = true;
    Selenide.open("https://www.instagram.com/");

    webDriver = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver();
}

public void login(String userName, String password) {

    WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(webDriver);

    Selenide.element(Selectors.byName("username")).setValue(userName);
    Selenide.element(Selectors.byName("password")).setValue(password);
    Selenide.elements(Selectors.byTagName("button")).get(1).click();
}
```